# Initializing H2 database in a Spring Boot application fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

Consider the following JPA entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AddressEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String city;
  private String postalCode;
  private String street;
  private String houseNumber;

}
```

I have created a Spring Boot application, which should create this table inside an H2 database and initialize it with some values. To achieve this, I have configured the application in the following way:

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:/testdB
    username: sa
    password:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    generate-ddl: true
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  sql:
    init:
      data-locations:
        - classpath:addresses.sql
```

My addresses.sql looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO ADDRESSES (ID, CITY, POSTAL_CODE, STREET, HOUSE_NUMBER)
VALUES (0, 'NYC', '10020', 'Main Street', '32 A')
```

When starting my app, I run into a `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException`. It says

`expected "DIRECT, SORTED, DEFAULT, VALUES, SET, (, WITH, SELECT, TABLE, VALUES";`.

I am at the end of my knowledge here. The syntax seems correct to me. When starting the app without initializing the tables, the tables are created. I can write data into my addresses table inside the H2 console using the exact same sql script I am using to initialize the table. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Omit the `ID` that is autogenerated, so handled automatically.

Comment: maybe a stupid idea, but easy to try: what if you write your SQL in one line? I have a feeling that it doesn't recognise the second line as a part of the query.

Comment: Allright, thx for your help, guys! @AndrejIstomin it's my formatter that puts the VALUES part of my query into the next line. The issue, however, seems to be a missing semicolon at the end of each statement. I am pretty sure I had tried this out before, but it is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a ; to the end of the sql file. That should fix your issue.